# Form interceptor, populate a form field without touching the original application

Tags: python, django

Picture an application written in Django, it displays a simple form. Without touching the application you would like to pre-populate one of the form fields when its rendered in a template.

Again you don't want to touch the original application or it's form at all.

At a guess, this is an interceptor, correct? In Django one assumes this is known as middleware?

My question is, how is this scenario handled in Django and can describe the method to me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this line in view after form module import and before creating form instance (not using middleware):

```
from app.forms import AppForm
AppForm.base_fields['fieldname'].initial="your default value"
```

Middleware may looks like:

```
class InitialValues(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        from app.forms import AppForm
        AppForm.base_fields['fieldname'].initial="your default value"
```

It executes before `view`. You cant insert middleware into template rendering, only before and after view.

Comment: I don't want to change the view in the application.